# Is this the correct way to create a route to a specific .hbs file?

Tags: html, node.js

**This is my /forums page**

```
<div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title">2019/2020 Premier League Forum</h5>
  <a href="/Leagues/EnglishDivision/PremierLeague" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
</div>
```

For the above code you can see the `href` pointing to a directory to `premierLeague.hbs`.

**This is how my file structure looks.**

```
├── app.js
├── views/
│   ├── index.hbs
│   ├── forums.hbs
│   ├── login.hbs
│   ├── Leagues/
│       ├── EnglishDivision/
│           ├── PremierLeague.hbs
│   
├── routes/
│   ├── Pages.js
```

**This is my app.js**

```
// Public dir
var publicDir = path.join(__dirname, './public');
app.use(express.static(publicDir));

// Define routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/pages'));
```

**This is my pages.js**

```
// Forum
router.get('/forums', authController.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  if(req.user) {
    res.render('forums');
  } else {
    res.redirect('login');
  }
});

// English Division //

// Premier League
router.get('/Leagues/EnglishDivision/PremierLeague', authController.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  if(req.user) {
    res.render('./Leagues/EnglishDivision/PremierLeague');
  } else {
    res.redirect('login');
  }
});
```

**Question:**

In order for premier league html file to be accessed via the `a` tag from `forums` page, have I set the routing correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code you should be setting the template engine and the base views path, in the likes of

```
app.set('views', __dirname+'/views/');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

(I assume you have that figured out already)

Having said that, you can either reference a view by its location relative to the views setting, therefore:

```
res.render('Leagues/EnglishDivision/PremierLeague');
```

(note there's no leading `./` in there)

OR, reference a view by its template file path (without extension). If you do this, the relative path is computed using the base path from which you start your app. Therefore, if your structure looked like:

```
  /var/www/project
  │   
  ├─ packjage.json
  └─ src/
       │   
       ├── app.js
       ├── views/
       │   └─── index.hbs
       │   └─── Leagues/
       │       └─── EnglishDivision/
       │           └─── PremierLeague.hbs
       │   
       └─── routes/
          └── Pages.js
```

Moving to `/var/www/project` and executing `node src/app.js` means

```
res.render('./Leagues/EnglishDivision/PremierLeague');
```

Will look for a template at `/var/www/project/Leagues/EnglishDivision/PremierLeague.hbs`

Whereas moving to `/var/www/project/src` and executing `node app.js` would instead look for `/var/www/project/src/Leagues/EnglishDivision/PremierLeague.hbs`

If you need to reference the template by its filepath, you should use the absolute path. For example,  `__dirname` always holds the current folder, regardless of where were you when executing the start script. Which means`__dirname` called from `Pages.js` is `/var/www/project/src/routes`, and therefore

```
res.render(__dirname+'/../views/Leagues/EnglishDivision/PremierLeague');
```

Would point to the intended file.